# how to change periodic timer task to a dynamic timer task

Tags: android, timertask

I am building a radio streaming application. I need to update the user interface according to the track change. I have the call back time, I need to know how to implement dynamic timer task to be implemented.

- Get call back time
- Add call back time delay
- Get call back time
- Add call back time delay

That is basically what I'm trying to do. Could someone tell me an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want to update the track name from the streaming thread? Couldnt you just broadcast an Intent and register an Intent reciever that listens for that specific intent and then update the track name. Or isn't that what you look for?

Comment: I need to know how to periodically fetch the new track information. Displaying it is not an issue. The track callbacks are not at a fixed interval

Comment: Why not keep the current track saved and when a new track is going to be played Broadcast an Intent from the service to your activity with the track information. Would be one easy way. Or you might need to display more dynamic information during the song? Is that the case?

Comment: It's streaming, there is no changing of a track, it happens from the stream; I don't have control of it.

Comment: Ah, sorry. My bad. A bit confused today.